# FFmpeg rtp streaming opus file problems

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, rtsp, rtp, opus

i have the next situation.

1. Have file on remote VPS server.
2. I want that this file (opus codec) can be accessible through RTP on my android phone.
3. I tried ffmpeg with next command:

   ```
   ffmpeg -ar 44800 -i bon_jovi_loverboy.opus -acodec libopus -ac 1 -ab 96k -vn -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:5004 -loglevel 56
   ```

But got next error:

```
bon_jovi_loverboy.opus: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Full log:

root@cs82932:/home/rstream/rtstream/src# ffmpeg -ar 44800 -i bon_jovi_loverboy.opus -acodec libopus -ac 1 -ab 96k -vn -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:5004 -loglevel 56
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-ar' ... matched as option 'ar' (set audio sampling rate (in Hz)) with argument '44800'.

Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'bon_jovi_loverboy.opus'.

Reading option '-acodec' ... matched as option 'acodec' (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'libopus'.

Reading option '-ac' ... matched as option 'ac' (set number of audio channels) with argument '1'.

Reading option '-ab' ... matched as option 'ab' (audio bitrate (please use -b:a)) with argument '96k'.

Reading option '-vn' ... matched as option 'vn' (disable video) with argument '1'.

Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'rtp'.

Reading option 'rtp://127.0.0.1:5004' ... matched as output url.

Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument '56'.

Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument 56.

Successfully parsed a group of options.

Parsing a group of options: input url bon_jovi_loverboy.opus.
Applying option ar (set audio sampling rate (in Hz)) with argument 44800.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: bon_jovi_loverboy.opus.

[AVIOContext @ 0x965e60] Statistics: 36389 bytes read, 0 seeks
bon_jovi_loverboy.opus: Invalid data found when processing input

What wrong? Thanks

**UPD**

I update ffmpeg and streaming looks successfully.

```
    ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i 4a6u7-ptl2w.opus -acodec libopus -ac 1 -ab 
           96k -vn -f rtp rtp://95.213.195.192:5004/f.opus
ffmpeg version 3.2.4-1~16.04.york1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.1 (Ubuntu 5.4.1-5ubuntu2~16.04.york1) 20170210
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~16.04.york1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, ogg, from '4a6u7-ptl2w.opus':
  Duration: 00:02:34.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 69 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc57.77.100 libopus
Output #0, rtp, to 'rtp://95.213.195.192:5004/f.opus':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus (libopus), 48000 Hz, mono, flt, 96 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 libopus
SDP:
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 95.213.195.192
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 57.56.101
m=audio 5004 RTP/AVP 97
b=AS:96
a=rtpmap:97 opus/48000/2

Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (opus (native) -> opus (libopus))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=   44893kB time=00:52:18.12 bitrate= 117.2kbits/s speed=56.5x
```

But when i try to connect by rtp from local PC (VLC Player) i get the exception:

```
         core error: socket bind error: Cannot assign requested address
         core error: open of `rtp://95.213.195.192:5004/f.opus' failed
```

When i try ffplay on remote pc (same where ffmpeg):

```
    ffplay rtp://95.213.195.192:5004/f.opus

ffplay version 3.2.4-1~16.04.york1 Copyright (c) 2003-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.1 (Ubuntu 5.4.1-5ubuntu2~16.04.york1) 20170210
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~16.04.york1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Segmentation fault
```

Can you help me? Thanks

**95.213.195.192 - IP of my remote server with file**

Comment: Your `ffmpeg` is old. [Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) a new one and try again without the input option `-ar 44800`.

Comment: I download ffmpeg i tried again. Can you please look at updated question? Thanks

Comment: May be i need ffserver?